# either fail and done of ajax deferred exceute

Tags: jquery

I try to use deferred instead of error & success callback in `$.ajax`,so I wrote following code

```
this.model.SyncByWS()
        .done(function(data)
                            {
                                console.log(data);
                            })
        .fail(
            console.log("Fail")
        );
```

and SyncByWS return `$.ajax`

```
    return  $.ajax({
                url:  '/traffic-counter/packets/get',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
             });
```

but in console I see "Fail" then `data`,it means first fail executed and then done.where is the problem?

Comment: it looks like a parse error, change the error log to `console.log('error', arguments)` and check the reason for errr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass a function reference to fail method.

```
.fail(function(){
           console.log("Fail");
      });
```

otherwise, console.log is getting exected and the returned value is passed to fail which is not a function reference. therefore you see "Fail" even before the ajax call is returned.

Comment: tnx so much,but what is different between function(data){console.log(data);} and console.log(data)?why passed function executed?

Comment: when you pass function(){ } you are passing a function reference which is executed later (when ajax call returns) whereas when you pass console.log() directly, you have already executed console.log method and the returned value is passed to done/fail method.

Comment: var obj = console.log; //log function reference is assigned to obj.
var obj = console.log(); // log function is executed and the returned value is assigned to obj.
hope this clarifies.